# by pass os.exit(1) from another function using interpreter stack or pdb in python

Tags: python-3.x, pdb

It should output:  'code is strong in this one' Followed by 'Welcome' how to bypass os.exit(1) from box() function using interpreter stack or pdb

```
import os
import inspect
import sys

def main():
    box()

    def over():
        print("disturbance in the code")
        os._exit(1)
        print('code is strong in this one')

    def win():
        print("Welcome")
    game_over()
    win()

def box():



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: In your code there is nothing in `box()`. Also where is `game_over()`? Do you mean `over()`?

Comment: yea I meant over and I wanna write a code in box()

Comment: You could make `box()` return say a Boolean value and depending on that value enable/disable `os.exit()` part in `over()`

Comment: @kuro can this be solved without modifying definition of over()? can we collect runtime trace and skip a line before it is called?